# Only first line of database code is returning

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am creating a website which calls a list of items from an external API.
The list has an "Order" button alongside it which when pressed, opens a modal with an order form.

The form is submitted, the API correctly receives the form data.  But I am trying to send the row information to the API aswell to inform what has actually been ordered.
The problem is that only the first row returned is ever sending no matter which line is "Ordered".

My html code file is:

```html
<head>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="body">
    <h1 class="header">Carpet Clearance</h1>
    <h2 class="header">
      The Mega Day carpet clearance list
    </h2>
</div>

<table class="table">
  <th>
    <td>Range</td>
    <td>Size</td>
    <td>Colour</td>
    <td>Cost</td>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td>Order</td>

  <tr *ngFor="let row of carpet;">
     <td class="td2">{{row.ID}}</td>
     <td>{{row.Range}}</td>
     <td>{{row.Size}}</td>
     <td>{{row.Colour}}</td>
     <td>{{row.Cost}}</td>
     <td>{{row.Value}}</td>
     <td><button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="btn">Order Item</button>

      <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
        <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-bottom w3-card-4">
          <header class="w3-container w3-teal"> 
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" 
            class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
            <h2 class="body">Order this item</h2>
          </header>
          <div class="modal">
            <p class="form">To order this range, please enter your customer account number, delivery address and Rep ID.</p>

            <form class="form" [formGroup]="checkoutForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(checkoutForm.value, row)">

              <div>
                <label for="Rep ID">
                  Rep ID<br>
                </label>
                <input id="Rep" type="text" formControlName="Rep">
              </div>

              <div>
                <label for="Account">
                  Account Number<br>
                </label>
                <input id="Account" type="text" formControlName="Account">
              </div>

              <div>
                <label for="address">
                  Address<br>
                </label>
                <input id="Address" type="text" formControlName="Address">
              </div>

              <button class="button" type="submit">Order</button>

            </form>
            </div>              
        </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My TS file is:

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ApiService } from '../../shared/api.service';
    import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-carpet',
      templateUrl: './carpet.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./carpet.component.scss']
    })
    export class CarpetComponent implements OnInit {
      checkoutForm;
      carpet = [];
      loadingIndicator = true;
      reorderable = true;

      columns = [
        { prop: 'ID', summaryFunc: () => null },
        { prop: 'Range', summaryFunc: () => null },
        { prop: 'Colour', summaryFunc: () => null },
        { prop: 'Size', summaryFunc: () => null },
        { prop: 'Cost', summaryFunc: () => null },
        { prop: 'Value', summaryFunc: () => null }
      ];

      constructor(private apiService: ApiService,
                  private formBuilder: FormBuilder
                  ) {
                    this.checkoutForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                      Rep: '',
                      Account: '',
                      Address: ''
                    });
                  }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.apiService.getCarpet()
          .subscribe((carpet: any[]) => {
            this.carpet = carpet;
            this.loadingIndicator = false;
          });

      }
      onSubmit(customerData, row) {
        const data = {
          customerData, row
        };
        this.apiService.sendFormData(data)
          .subscribe();
        this.checkoutForm.reset();

        console.warn('Your order has been submitted', customerData);
      }
    }
```

Can anyone point me towards the error here?

Comment: you should add `angular` tag as your code uses Angular Framework

Comment: Done, thank you.  Forgot that one!